# Creating Indexname Dynamically using Spring-Data Elasticsearch with @Document

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to get `indexname` dynamically in

```
@Document(indexName="Something",type="type")
```

I have tried using below code:

```
@Document(indexName="#{systemProperties['databaseName'] }", type = "dbtype")
```

but at runtime when I am sending two request from UI to get the data from ES from different indexes,it is not working properly.

what should I  do to  solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is, to work with NativeSearchQuerries.
There you can set the index to whatever you like:

```
NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withIndices(indexName)
                .withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("_all", request.getSearchTerm().getSearchString()))
                .withPageable(new PageRequest(request.getPaging(), request.getMaxResults()))
....
                .build();
        result =elastic.query(query, query->query2Result(query));
```

Comment: there is no `withIndices` in the latest version - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/NativeSearchQueryBuilder.html#withIndicesBoost-java.util.List-