# SpEL used in @Document indexName with spring data elasticsearch and spring boot is not being parsed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-el

looking for some help using the SpEL inside `@Document` annotation in reference to:

`spring-data-elasticsearch:3.2.3.RELEASE` and spring boot `2.2.1 RELEASE`

i am having trouble googling for help with this problem as the keywords pick up unrelated questions (i have seen the [other (unanswered) question about dynamic indexName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097197/creating-indexname-dynamically-using-spring-data-elasticsearch-with-document)).

i would like to set the

`@Document(indexName = "${es.index-name}", ...)`

with the value for the `indexName` derived from a property (`es.index-name`) value written in my `application.properties`.

it is instead using the literal String value `"${es.index-name}"` as the index name!

i have also tried creating a `@Component` called `EsConfig`

with a field `indexName` annotated with `@Value("${es.index-name}")`

and then trying to access this component property value using SpEL:

`@Document(indexName = "#{esConfig.indexName}", ...)`

but this does not work either (still parsing as literal String and complains of uppercase). i have confirmed through the debugger that the `EsConfig` component IS parsing the SpEL correctly and providing the right value. but it fails when reaching `@Document`

here are the full code snippets:

using `@Document` with SpEL accessing `application.properties`

```java
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@Document(indexName = "${es.index-name}", type = "tests")
public class TestDocument {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private String id;
}
```

`EsConfig data source Component` (tried with and without using Lombok)

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("esConfig")
public class EsConfig {
  @Value("${es.index-name}")
  private String indexName;

  public String getIndexName() {
    return indexName;
  }

  public void setIndexName(String indexName) {
    this.indexName = indexName;
  }
}
```

using `@Document` with SpEL accessing `EsConfig` `indexName` property

```java
@Data
@Document(indexName = "#{esConfig.indexName}", type = "tests")
public class TestDocument {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private String id;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reference your bean with the name and method:

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@esConfig.getIndexName()}")
```

Comment: my god thank you. this has been driving me insane for days

Comment: do you happen to know why neither "${es.index-name}" nor "#{esConfig.indexName}" worked?

Comment: the index name argument is parsed with a SpelExpressionParser that needs `#{...}`. and within that expression you need to reference the bean with `@` and you need to use the getter methods, no direkt property access. You can try `#{es.index-name}` but I'm not sure if the parsers uses the environemtn or only the available beans.

Comment: i see. what confused me is that my friend was using spring boot 2.1.x + spring data elasticsearch 3.1.x and for him @Document(indexName = "#{esConfig.indexName}") did work. i could not figure out why just moving up the minor versions had such a drastic difference. and nothing in the change logs reflecting this. thank you again for your help

Comment: strange ideed, I am not aware of a change at that place. But glad I could help you

Comment: I have spent months trying to set the index-name dynamically for different environments.  Thanks for this solution!