# ReactiveCrudRepository supply with index name

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring-data with reactive support for Elasticsearch:

```
@Repository
public interface UserDocumentRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<UserDocument, UUID> {

}
```

For now, my `UserDocument` is annotated with `@Document(indexName = "user-*")` It is working properly for searching (as I am using ES supplied from Kafka-connect, my service will not create new documents).

My problem is that I have multiple environments dev/test when I need to parametrize index name for each cluster (using the same elastic search, with different index names).

So for dev, I need `dev-user-*` and for the test, I need `test-user-*`. I can use `ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate` where you can supply indexName, but how to do it with `ReactiveCrudRepository`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SpEL expression in your `@Document` annotation. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59278195/spel-used-in-document-indexname-with-spring-data-elasticsearch-and-spring-boot) and my answer there about the syntax.

**Edit:**

Just a couple of examples how to build the index name dynamically:

If you have a configuration from the application.properties named *env-name*:

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@environment.getProperty('env-name')}-index-*")
```

I you have a bean named *environmentProvider* with a *getEnv()* method:

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@environmentProvider.getEnv()}-index-*")
```

Comment: Somehow this is working with `spring-data-elasticsearch 4.0.0.RELEASE` but for other versions, such as 4.1 upwards `org.springframework.data.spel` is missing `ExpressionDependencies.class` if I am correct, at least that what my error says. 

Was is deprecated? I don't know how to figure that out... And is there an alternative now?