# SpEL used in @Mapping mappingPath and @Setting settingPath with spring data elasticsearch and spring boot is not being parsed

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have problem similar to solved in this question [@Document SpEL parse problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59278195/spel-used-in-document-indexname-with-spring-data-elasticsearch-and-spring-boot),

with

> @Mapping

and

> @Setting

With bean defined path:

```
@Bean 
public String mySettingsFilePath() {
    return "classpath:index-settings.json";
}
```

SpEL in @Setting annotation, like @Setting(settingPath = "#{@mySettingsFilePath}"),  wasn't been parsed.
I got this error:

```
WARN o.s.d.e.c.ResourceUtil [main] - Failed to load file from url: #{@mySettingsFilePath}: class path resource [#{@mySettingsFilePath}] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I would like to use SpEL in @Mapping and @Setting annotations as i can do it with @Document annotation.

Answer (score 0):

SpEL resolution is  not supported for these two annotations. But the parameters are resolved as classpath resources, so you should just pass `"/index-settings.json"` to the annotation parameter.

Comment: I'd try to implement custom ResourceLoader, but it not used to find resources in @Mapping(mappingPath ) or @Setting(settingPath ). How to force applicationContext ClassLoader to load resource by path depends on configuration - i don't know